# bundling source code in docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, docker, production-environment

I have setup my app to run in a docker container and I'm pretty excited about it.

In dev, I can build the container super fast as the source code and assets for the container are outside the container context - then I simply map the wwwroot directory into the container using the -v flag on the docker run command. It works great!

However, now I have setup an Elastic Beanstalk application (configured for docker) and I'm looking to deploy my container to it. I'm thinking the -v approach for production is not the correct one and that I perhaps need to have a separate Dockerfile for production which physically `COPY`'s my source code into the the container? Then perhaps that is the container I push up to docker hub and somehow send over to Elastic Beanstalk.

Or is there a better approach here? I haven't been able to find any clear direction on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice specifies that the Dockerfile should be as ephemeral as possible. Hence the flag `-v` is actually the right way of sharing the code. The code *should not* be into the image.

Comment: The code should NOT be in the image, even in a production environment? Then where should it be?

Comment: On the same host (or storage available) and shared through volume. If you ever embedded your code, at each commit you would need a new image (<joke>do you even version bro?</joke>). Docker aims at ease the step between dev and deployment, which means the system state, the packages, the system itself, not the code that evolve far faster than all its required ecosystem. Hence the code shared through -v and not embedded.

Comment: Lol strong joke work. Yes, what you're describing is an approach that seems very natural to me as naturally our application code will change FAR more often than the ecosystem. That said, I thought what you're describing was actually considered bad practice in that the Docker container becomes less portable as suddenly it's dependent on the environment in which it's run and is no longer a completely "standalone" entity.

Comment: Well, do not feel bad to embed the code within an image on each release though. The [tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/debian/tags/) are made for this usage. The _code_ (dev) should not be embedded, the _binaries_ (ready to be deployed) should (yet the frontier fade out when it's php- or python-code and that there is no compilation step).

Answer (score 1):

For production, you'll need a Dockerfile that copies the assets (source code or binaries) required for the web application into the container. Otherwise, deploying it anywhere other than your local computer will not work.

Ideally, the development and production Dockerfiles should be identical. This way, your development happens in an environment that matches (as close as possible) to production.

Comment: Copying the assets for production makes sense, thank you. But in dev, to copy the assets into the container would mean you would need to rebuild on every code change, would it not? Seems like a real pain.

Comment: Most development includes a repeated "build" stage (change code, build, test, repeat). Building your container (and copying the assets) is just that.

Comment: Great point, thanks for sharing. We do have a build process but only run the build when we're ready to commit, not necessary after every code change just to see the app running the new code (before you're ready to commit). Regardless, I appreciate your insight and I see now how running the docker image build process could be worked into your overall application build process.